# shift taylor series coefficient

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let say I have analytic function $f(z)$ with taylor series $\sum a_nZ^n $

I want to find function $g(z)$ that It's taylor is $\sum a_{n+1} Z^n $

I need that for every $n>1$ : $g ^{(n-1)}(z)$ = $\frac{f ^{(n)}(z)}{n}$

I can't solve it...your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ then
$$ \frac{f(z)-a_0}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} z^n. $$

Comment: Bingo. So simple. thanks.